# Methods to estimate bivariate survival function under *bivariate* censoring

Tags: survival, censoring, copula, kaplan-meier

I am looking at the relation between two time-to-event variables subject to censoring. The seminal work from Lin and Ying is unfortunately paywalled (https://www.jstor.org/stable/2337178), but I understand the major limitation is that the general method only admits *univariate* censoring. Has any work dealt with the estimation of a bivariate survival function in the case of *bivariate* censoring that doesn't require parametric models for the response and imputation?

Answer (score 2):

Dabrowska [discusses](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/annals-of-statistics/volume-16/issue-4/Kaplan-Meier-Estimate-on-the-Plane/10.1214/aos/1176351049.full) this problem, and [Prentice and Cai](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2336781).  Oakes has also [proposed](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2345500) semiparametric models, where the marginal survival functions are arbitrary but the dependence is controlled by a single parameter.